# I can not assign a new user a app on MS azure

Tags: azure, office365, office-app

[image]

I need to assign a new user. But I can not, because assign link is disable.
So, how can I assign a new user for web app?

Comment: Doesn't it say `User assignments are currently not required`? You need to require user assignment on the Configure tab.

Comment: yes I did enabled "user assignment requied to access app". but not assign:(